# failed to upgrade a token

Tags: youtube-api

I was testing Zend Gdata 1.10.1 in my localhost.
I downloaded Zend Gdate from this link:
http://framework.zend.com/download/webservices

Inside the Zend Gdata zip file, there was a folder called demos.
I extracted it and used the YouTudeVideoApp to upload a sample video to Youtube.

But every time after I logged into Youtube, before it redirected me to my localhost, 
I received a warning message like this warning message:

> localhost: This website is registered
>   with Google to make authorization
>   requests, but has not been configured
>   to send requests securely. We
>   recommend that you continue the
>   process only if you trust the
>   following destination:
>   localhost:8080/youtube/operations.php

So I googled on how to resolve the problem of getting this warning message when
I saw some people suggesed changing the value of $secure to True in operation.php.
Here is the script mentioned:

```
function generateAuthSubRequestLink($nextUrl = null)
{
    $scope = 'http://gdata.youtube.com';
    $secure = true;
    $session = true;

    if (!$nextUrl) {
        generateUrlInformation();
        $nextUrl = $_SESSION['operationsUrl'];
    }

    $url = Zend_Gdata_AuthSub::getAuthSubTokenUri($nextUrl, $scope, $secure, $session);
    echo '<a href="' . $url
        . '"><strong>Click here to authenticate with YouTube</strong></a>';
}
```

After I altered the value of $secure to True,
I found that the warning message changed to this:

> localhost: Registered, secure. This
>   website is registered with Google to
>   make authorization requests

The new warning message is somehow shorter and looks better than the previous warning message.
But once I pressed the Allow Access button, it turned out to be this:

> ERROR - Token upgrade for
>   CI3M6_Q3EOGkxoL-_____wEYjffToQQ failed
>   : Token upgrade failed. Reason:
>   Invalid AuthSub header. Error 401
>   ERROR - Unknown search type - ''

I don't know why this happened.

Could you help me solve the problem please?

Answer (score 0):

edit your php.ini file and enable the openssl extensions

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

restart the httpd or IIS server